# How to set color for a font class- object in VB.NET..?

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts

How to set color for a font class- object  in VB.NET..?
i mean..

```
   Dim MYfONT As New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16, FontStyle.Bold)
e.Graphics.DrawString(TabMain.TabPages(e.Index).Text, MYfONT, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, paddedBounds)
```

how can i set this font class object(MYfONT) - color to Black. ?

Comment: I think that the color is controlled by the ForeColor property of a control object that supports text, ie TextBox.

Comment: That depends. How/where are you using this font?

Comment: Using with Rectangle.. on tabheader.

Comment: i have editted the query - with my code..//!

Answer (score 3):

Just expand your `SystemBrushes.HighlightText` to a `New SolidBrush(Color.Black)`

```
Public Sub DrawStringRectangleF(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)    
    ' Create string to draw.'
    Dim drawString As [String] = "Sample Text"

    ' Create font and brush.'
    Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 16)
    Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

    ' Create rectangle for drawing.'
    Dim x As Single = 150.0F
    Dim y As Single = 150.0F
    Dim width As Single = 200.0F
    Dim height As Single = 50.0F
    Dim drawRect As New RectangleF(x, y, width, height)

    ' Draw rectangle to screen.'
    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height)

    ' Draw string to screen.'
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect)
End Sub
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6.aspx)